# Engineering manager certifications

Tags: germany, certification

Would a certification help to find a job as engineering manager (or 20 years experience in the IT field as developer and leader are enough)? If so, which one?

Comment: Depends on whether whoever you are interviewing with is impressed by that particular certificate.

Comment: At twenty years in you should be *granting* certs, not sitting for them.

Comment: In Germany certificate matter, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: Clearly there seems to be some language barrier here, by certificates do you mean some kind of exam ? You mentioned Germany, add that tag please. Also, please explain a little what the certification you're talking about means compared to regular school.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t i am talking about "certifications" like ITIL or Scrum Master Certification, Professional Scrum Developer Certification, ... I don'tknow if some of those are a "must have" for an EM

Comment: @NewUbuntuUser Those seem pretty oriented towards building programs and applications, not engineering or managing at all, are you expecting to be an Engineering Manager in a Tech business ? Could you explain what an Engineering Manager does ? I can't understand what that position even is supposed to do, seems like a filler job, do you "Manage" Engineers ? Also, 20 years in IT will never make you an Engineer, at best you'll become a Development Manager.

Comment: Can you maybe give us the German job title? I suspect it is not actually "Engineering Manager".

Answer (score 5):

I have never heard of any certification that an engineering manager needs to do his job well.

I don't think a company would look for a certification when hiring an engineering manager. They would rather look for your real experience as a manager in your previous jobs.

Comment: Certificate like ITIL, PSD, PSM,...

Answer (score 0):

> Would a certification help to find a job as engineering manager (or 20
> years experience in the IT field as developer and leader are enough)?
> If so, which one?

Always start with the job advertisements you would be applying for. Note if there are certifications either listed as required or desired. Failing to have required certifications will eliminate you for consideration. Missing desired ones may or may not impact your ability to get hired.

Not all jobs you would be interested in are the same. Some may require certifications due to the exact tasks you would be responsible for, others would not have those requirements.